# Adding const-ness to opaque handle

Tags: c, constants, typedef, handle, opaque-pointers

If I have created a C module that presents a handle to the user with a pointer to a forward declared struct, like so:

```
typedef struct FOO_Obj *FOO_Handle;
```

If I then declare function prototypes that use it as a `const` qualified parameter thusly:

```
void FOO_work(const FOO_Handle fooHandle);
```

How is the `const`-ness applied?

```
const struct FOO_Obj *FOO_Handle // A
struct FOO_Obj *const FOO_Handle  // B
const struct FOO_Obj *const FOO_Handle  // C
```

Or is it **UB**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B. ( There is no undefined behavior with the code you presented. )

The function call

```
void FOO_work(const FOO_Handle fooHandle);
```

is equivalent to

```
void FOO_work(struct FOO_Obj* const fooHandle);
```

Variable `fooHandle` in the function will becode a const pointer to a non-const `struct FOO_Obj` object. You will not be able to add the const qualifier to `fooHandle` to make it a pointer to a const object.

Instead, if you want to have a pointer to a const object, and keep the struct hidden, you must make another typedef:

```
typedef const struct FOO_Obj* FOO_ConstHandle;
```

Comment: Thanks. A `const` pointer to non-`const` data is what I need, so I was on the right track